# Strange incongruent output for both nc and fifo

Tags: bash, shell, netcat, fifo, mkfifo

I have this exact code:

```
#!/bin/bash

gtimeout(){
  if type -f gtimeout &> /dev/null; then
    command gtimeout "$@"
  else
    timeout "$@"
  fi
}

export -f gtimeout;


on_first_match(){
   local pattern="$1"  # The pattern to search for
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ "$line" == *"$pattern"* ]]; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done
}

export -f on_first_match


write_to_server(){
  echo -e "$?" | nc 0.0.0.0 3333
}

export -f write_to_server

(

set +e;
sleep 2;

  (
     gtimeout 15 docker logs -f rabbitmq-node1 | on_first_match 'Starting listener on';
     write_to_server
  ) &


  (
    gtimeout 15 docker logs -f mongodb-node1 | on_first_match 'waiting for connections';
    write_to_server
  ) &


  (
    gtimeout 15 docker logs -f elasticsearch-node1 | on_first_match 'started';
    write_to_server
  ) &


  (
     gtimeout 15 docker logs -f rabbitmq-node2 | on_first_match 'Starting listener on';
     write_to_server
  ) &


  (
    gtimeout 15 docker logs -f mongodb-node2 | on_first_match 'waiting for connections';
    write_to_server
  ) &


  (
    gtimeout 15 docker logs -f elasticsearch-node2 | on_first_match 'started';
    write_to_server
  ) &


  (
     gtimeout 15 docker logs -f rabbitmq-node3 | on_first_match 'Starting listener on';
     write_to_server
  ) &


  (
    gtimeout 15 docker logs -f mongodb-node3 | on_first_match 'waiting for connections';
    write_to_server
  ) &


  (
    gtimeout 15 docker logs -f elasticsearch-node3 | on_first_match 'started';
    write_to_server
  ) &


) &

gtimeout 30 nc -k -l 3333 | while IFS= read -r line; do
      echo "Received: $line";
done
```

the output I get is like so:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: mongodb-node1
Error response from daemon: No such container: rabbitmq-node2
Error response from daemon: No such container: rabbitmq-node1
Error response from daemon: No such container: elasticsearch-node2
Error response from daemon: No such container: elasticsearch-node1
Error response from daemon: No such container: mongodb-node2
Error response from daemon: No such container: mongodb-node3
Error response from daemon: No such container: rabbitmq-node3
Error response from daemon: No such container: elasticsearch-node3
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
```

(with just 5 received lines, sometimes 4, sometimes 6 but never 9 as expected)

but I expect this:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: mongodb-node1
Error response from daemon: No such container: rabbitmq-node2
Error response from daemon: No such container: rabbitmq-node1
Error response from daemon: No such container: elasticsearch-node2
Error response from daemon: No such container: elasticsearch-node1
Error response from daemon: No such container: mongodb-node2
Error response from daemon: No such container: mongodb-node3
Error response from daemon: No such container: rabbitmq-node3
Error response from daemon: No such container: elasticsearch-node3
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
Received: 0
```

with 9 received lines.

Anyone know what is going on here? (The same behavior happens when I switch the code out for a mkfifo instead of a socket).

Comment: Perhaps a shorter example would help people reproduce it (bypassing `gtimeout`, for example, and assuming the behavior remains), but wouldn't `nc -k -l 3333` provide as much output as there were incoming connections? And so the `while/read`  loop would dutifully report all the (apparent) zeroes that came from `nc`?

Comment: I had to use flock to create a lock so that there were not simultaneous writes to the file/socket which is very strange. Using flock it worked fine. Not happy about that though.

Comment: See `man listen`. I don't know what default `backlog` value `nc` uses, but it might be 5, as with `socat`.